# How to specify where clause with nullable column

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a sample table like blow.

[id] [Name] [DeleteFlg]
1    Apple    NULL
2    Lemon    True
3    Grape    False

And I want to select like the SQL below in Linq.

```
select *
from Sample
where DeleteFlg != True
```

But, this returns nothing (ret.Count = 0).

```
var ret = (
  from f in db.Sample
  where f.DeleteFlg != true
  select new { Name = f.Name }
)
```

How can I select except Lemon with DeleteFlg?

Comment: Please provide more details in the question to ensure there's a clarity regarding what you expect, I have shown in my answer that for IEnumerable (Linq to Objects), current query will work perfectly fine

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I provided SQL query and other ppl understood enough.

Comment: If you have explained enough, then how come I am able to make your Linq query work as expected, point out the issue in that program, it is producing expected result

Comment: @MrinalKamboj If I have not explained enough, why two guys could provide me answers what I wanted to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing a null check (seeing as you are using EF).

```
where !f.DeleteFlg.HasValue || !f.DeleteFlg.Value
```

should select those entries where DeleteFlg IS NULL or where DeleteFlg is equal to false.

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns one row with Name='Grape'.
So, if you whant the linq query with the same result you need this one:

```
var ret = (
    from f in db.Sample
    where f.DeleteFlg.HasValue && !f.DeleteFlg.Value
    select new {Name = f.Name}
  ).ToList();
```

or

```
var ret = db.Sample.Where(f => f.DeleteFlag.HasValue && !f.DeleteFlag.Value).ToList();
```

These two linq-expressions returns one item in a list.

Comment: Correct solution needs an || in the where clause as its shown in the selected answer, your solution will again lead to in correct result